# Problem (exercise) books in commutative algebra

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, soft-question, problem-solving

I am looking for problem books in commutative algebra. I could find a book named *Exercises in Classical Ring Theory* by T Y Lam. This book contains problems about non commutative rings also, but I need to know if there is a similar book exclusively for commutative algebra.

Comment: Take the exercises from Atiyah MacDonalds, see the duplicate below.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is there a book similar to Exercises in Classical Ring Theory? That was my question

Comment: Yes, Atiyah MacDonald. You can also use both books. In Classical Ring Theory you can skip the non-commutative exercises and replace them by Atiyah MacDonald exercises.